# Failed to load viewstate in devexpress

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

This problem is creating lot of trouble in devexpress master detail gridview

"Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request."

i want to know why this happens in the first place, so that i can check my code. thats why i am not posting my code

Its urgent :)